# jQuery acts differently after Rails upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm upgrading an old Rails 3.0 application that uses jQuery 1.8.2.
The code below used to work on our Rails 3 app, but now throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of null`:

```
$.ajax(...).always(function(data){
  console.log(data.status);
})
```

I do know how to fix this JS issue (`function(data, textStatus, xhr)` ... `xhr.status`), but what I don't understand is how that could have worked before the upgrade, and what made the behaviour change.

`$().jquery;` returns "1.8.2" on both Rails 3 and Rails 5, and we use the same jquery-min file

Comment: jQuery was [dropped as a Rails dependency](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/27113)  for the 5.1 release, are you including it specifically in your `application.js`?

Comment: @ronan_mac yes. Not only that, we even use the same file for both Rails versions... `$().jquery;` has the same result too.